# Join Different tables using Criteria

Tags: nhibernate, join, nhibernate-criteria, detachedcriteria

I have two different entities, I need to join them based on a common entity property between them, but there's no path to get from the entity the Criteria is created on to the other one!
Please help.

Thanks

---

**--Edit--**

Sorry, maybe my question was not clear.

I have the following Entities:

```
class A
{
    string Text {get;set;}
}
class B 
{
    string Text {get;set;}
}
class C
{
    string Text {get;set;}
    B B_Object_1 {get;set;}
}
class D
{
    A A_Object {get;set;}
    B B_Object_2 {get;set;}
}
```

what I'm trying to do is creating a criteria on **D** entity, yet, I need to join it with **C** entity , and the join condition is **D.B_Object_2 == C.B_Object_1**

because on projection, or what I need to be selected as a results contains:
D.A_Object.Text and C.B_Object_1.Text based on my join condition above.

Can this be done using Criteria or with the assistance of DetachedCriteria?

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific, give us an example, show use the entities involved, etc?  At the moment, this question is a bit too vague to answer.

Comment: That's much better.  Are you able to express the query you are shooting for using SQL?

Comment: I need to Join D and C based on this condition "D.B_Object_2 == C.B_Object_1", and then select Data from D, and C.B_Object_1 at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's not possible. At least did not find any neat solution. But there are two workarounds:

1. [Query only properties](http://ayende.com/blog/4054/nhibernate-query-only-properties). Not sure Criteria API could handle this, but HQL defenitely does.
2. Plain old SQL-queries - session.CreateSQLQuery().